# Ideating how to send notifications for chat rooms?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, react-native-gifted-chat

We provide different chat channels for users to talk about various topics.

Every user has access to the chat channels. Here is the code for a channel:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        messages: [],
        currentUser: null,
        isLoading: true,
        messageID: "",
        isTyping: false,
        messageText: "",
        roomName: this.props.route.params.roomName,
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------
async componentDidMount (){

    **Code to get current messages**
    
}

//Add a message to firestore
onSend = async(message) => {

    this.setState({isTyping: true,})

    const messageID = uuidv4()

    await Firebase.firestore()
    .collection("chatRooms")
    .doc(this.state.roomName)
    .collection("messages")
    .doc(messageID)
    .set({
        _id: messageID,
        text: message[0].text,
        createdAt: new Date(message[0].createdAt),
        user: {
            _id: this.state.currentUser.id,
            name: this.state.currentUser.name,
            avatar: this.state.currentUser.avatar,
        },
        
    })

     Analytics.logEvent(`ChatMessageSent_${this.state.roomName}`)

}
```

Now, when a user sends a message in any channel, I want to send a notification to all users who have push notifications on that there is a new message in *xyz* channel.

My thoughts are to do this in onSend():

When a user sends a new message, call a firebase function to send a notification to all users that there is a new message in *xyz* channel.

I can't think of another way to do this. I already know how to send push notifications, how to change a tab bar icon if there are notifications, ETC, but am having trouble ideating how exactly to go about this since there are multiple channels.

I am also worried that these notifications will be too "spammy". Perhaps sending out notifications if they have x amount of unread messages across all channels?

Let me know if you have a better idea, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are on the right path. You can avoid sending to many messages by creating some kind of condition (if they have x ammount of unread messages across all channels).

Comment: @marian.vladoi thank you! that is what I intend on doing :)